# debug: Getting error in ouput of EAN program

Tags: c++, char

I've been debugging my EAN program for over a day and still cannot find where the error is that's making the program crash. I've so far whittled it down to one function, the strwithstyle function, as when it's not called the program runs fine(albeit with no style characters added). When called however, the program displays its output in a garbled mess and the program triggers a breakpoint. If anyone can tell me why this may be happening that would be of great help!

```
    void EAN::toStrWithStyle(char* str) const {
    if (isRegistered()) {
        if (choice == '-') {
            sprintf(str, "%s-%s-%s-%s-%c", prefix, area, publisher, title, ean[strlen(ean) - 1]);
        }
        else if (choice == ' ') {
            sprintf(str, "%s %s %s %s %c", prefix, area, publisher, title, ean[strlen(ean) - 1]);
        }
        else  {
            toStr(str);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the display function(so you can get an idea of where the parameter str comes from):

```
    void EAN::display(std::ostream& os) const {
    char* strmem = nullptr;
    if (isRegistered()) {
        strmem = new char[strlen(ean) + 5];
        toStrWithStyle(strmem);
    }
    else {
        strmem = new char[strlen(ean) + 1];
        toStr(strmem);
    }
    os << right << setw(17) << strmem;
    delete [] strmem;
    strmem = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Is "str" big enough to hold the sprintf'd string? If it isn't, your symptoms pretty much match what you might see from overwriting memory that doesn't belong to str.

For C++ you should seriously consider using something like boost::format or even a simple std::stringstream to build up the string in a typesafe manner that ends up with less potential for buffer overflows.

Comment: Yes, I even tried upping the amount of character str can hold to 500 and the output still remains the same, with a garbled mess and a triggered breakpoint. I can post the other functions if others need more of a reference

Comment: Given the signature of your display function, I'd seriously recommend looking into using std::string and boost::format or std::stringstream. At the moment the way it's written it's not exception save *and* you have the "mystery crash". Also, have you verified that all of your string parameters contain or point to valid strings?